# JQuery Problem With attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a short snippet of HTML (it contains all relevant HTML and javascript code):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.remove-temporary-photo').click(function() {
        var url = '/my-account/remove-media/id/' + $(this).attr('id');
        $.get(url, function(data) {
            //
        });
        var id;
        id = $('ul.inl').attr('id');
        alert(id);
        //$.get('/my-account/temporary-album-photos/id/' + id, function(data) {
        //    $('#temporaryPhotos').html(data);
        //});
    });
});    //]]>
</script>
<ul class="inl" id="4">
    <li>
        <a href="#53" class="img"><img src="/uploads/photos-thumbs/53.jpg" alt="Public Photo #53" /></a>
        <p class="options">
            <input type="text" name="title53" id="53" value="Title..." class="title" style="width: 81px; margin-top: 5px; border: 0;" />
            <a href="#53" class="blue remove-temporary-photo" id="53">remove</a>
        </p>
    </li>

</ul>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
```

Notice this line:

```
alert(id);
```

What I get is a blank popup window. Shouldn't id be equal to 4? I don't understand it. The reason why this matters is because I need the id for the next three/four lines of code that are commented now.

EDIT:

Now, I'm using valid ids but the alerts are still empty:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.remove-temporary-photo').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id.substr(2);
        alert(id);
        //var url = '/my-account/remove-media/id/' + id;
        //$.get(url, function(data) {
            //
        //});
        id = $('.inl:first').attr('id');
        id = id.substr(2);
        alert(id);
        //$.get('/my-account/temporary-album-photos/id/' + id, function(data) {
        //    $('#temporaryPhotos').html(data);
        //});
    });
});    //]]>
</script>
<?php if (count($this->photos) > 0): ?>
<ul class="inl" id="id<?php echo $this->escape($this->a->id); ?>">
<?php foreach ($this->photos as $p): ?>
    <li>
        <a href="#id<?php echo $this->escape($p->id); ?>" class="img"><img src="/<?php echo $this->escape($p->thumb_path); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escape($p->title); ?>" /></a>
        <p class="options">
            <input type="text" name="title<?php echo $this->escape($p->id); ?>" id="id<?php echo $this->escape($p->id); ?>" value="Title..." class="title" style="width: 81px; margin-top: 5px; border: 0;" />
            <a href="#id<?php echo $this->escape($p->id); ?>" class="blue remove-temporary-photo" id="<?php echo $this->escape($p->id); ?>">remove</a>
        </p>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Why? I don't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your IDs are invalid - they're not allowed to start with digits.
According to the [HTML 4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-id):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the ids, they are valid now but still, the alert is empty. I have posted the updated code above.

Comment: Both alerts are empty actually, I don't understand this.

Comment: Also, the anchor and inputs have the same ID.

Comment: Just to let you know I have solved the issue by parsing the js code with PHP and adding the correct id with PHP before the script added to the <script> tag.